# Generic class definition with both generic type constraint and inherited type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.0

I was wondering if it possible to have both a generic type constraint and an inherited type?

I could not figure the syntax out for myself or think of a possible example I could look at.

Code Example:

```
public class Test<T> where T : ITest, new() : IBaseTest {  }
```

Is it possible to achieve a class definition like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`public class Test<T> : IBaseTest where T : ITest, new()  {  }`

Your class will implement interface `IBaseTest`, and generic parameter `T` constrained to types that are implementing interface `ITest` and having default (parameterless) constructor.

Is this what you meant?